# CSS Animation Creation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am new to CSS animations and have very little knowledge with animations specifically. My intention is to have the grey box come down from the top line above the login / register section. At the moment I have only got it fading in. If anybody can help that would be great.
Please run the code in your own browser to see how it's supposed to run.
P.S. The animation runs when the button is clicked.

If anybody can help that would be great.

```js
var regbutton = document.getElementById('Register_Button');

var regpopup = document.getElementById('cover_for_register');

regbutton.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    regpopup.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px auto;
}
button, input, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, a{       /* State that these particular elements be "fantasy" */
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
#home_container{
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#home_left_section{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 55%;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#2aefff, #ffffff);
}
#home_right_section{
    float: right;
    height: 100%!important;
    width: 45%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #888;
    z-index: 10000;
    background-color:aliceblue;
}
#home_right_section h1{
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#home_right_section h2{
    margin: 0px;
}
#home_right_section hr {
    margin: 0px;
}
#login_register_container{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#login_container{
    text-align: center;               /* If border is created, width must be changed */
    float: left;
    padding-right:50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.login_input_fields{
    border-radius:5px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.register_popup_foot{
    
}
#register_container{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align:left;
}
#cover_for_register{
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    height: 52%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: animateone;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateone {
    from {min-height:200px; opacity:0}
}
#Register_Button{
    z-index: 10000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    width:100px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
#Register_Button_Container{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 217px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PTrainMeCSS.css">
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=deive-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="PTrainMeJavascript.js"></script>
</head>
    <div id="home_container">
        <section id="home_left_section">
            <h1></h1>
        </section>
        <section id="home_right_section">
            <h1>GetFit</h1>
            <hr />
            <h3 id="welcome_text">Here you can find whatever service you may want throughout the fitness industry</h3>
            <hr />
            <div id="login_register_container">
                <section id="login_container">
                            <h2>Login</h2>
                            <form>
                                <br />
                                    <input class="login_input_fields" type="text" name="Username" maxlength="10" placeholder="Username / E-Mail" /><br /><br />
                                    <input class="login_input_fields" type="password" name="Password" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                            </form>
                                <footer class="register_popup_foot">
                                    <a class="register_loginform_foot_text" href="Forgot Password.html">Reset Password</a>
                                    <br />
                                </footer>
                </section>
                <div id="Register_Button_Container">
                <section>
                    <button id="Register_Button">Register</button>
                </section>
                </div>
                <div id="cover_for_register">
                <section id="register_container">
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                    <form>
                        <br />
                            <input class="login_input_fields" type="text" name="Username" maxlength="10" placeholder="Username"/>
                            <br /><br />
                            <input class="login_input_fields" type="text" name="E-Mail" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
                            <br /><br />
                            <input class="login_input_fields" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
                            <br /><br />
                            <label>Age:</label>
                <br /> <select type="option" name="Age">
                <option></option>
                <option>13</option>
                <option>14</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>17</option>
                <option>18</option>
                </select><br /><br />
                            Security Question: <br /><select type="select" name="Security Question">
                <option>Please select one.</option>
                <option>What was my school teachers first name?</option>
                <option>Whats my favourite chip flavour?</option>
                <option>What type was my first car?</option>
                <option>What was the name of my first school?</option>
                <option>What are my parents names?</option>
                <option>How many siblings do i have?</option>
                <option>What was the address of my first house?</option>
                </select><br /> <br />
                Answer: <br /> <input type="text" name="Answer">
                <a href="">Why</a><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PTrainMeJavascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution,

make   #cover_for_register =  z-index highest from others and change your animation to

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateone {
from { top:-52%;}

to {top: 5%;}//desired margin from top to cover your login page.

 }
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you have to change is as

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateone {
    from { height:0%;}
    to {height: 100%;}
 }
```

AND add below point in CSS...

add `top:0; position:absolute;` to `#cover_for_register`

add `position:relative;` `#login_register_container`

Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/dkrvl2011/se93orog/10/show/